# E-commerce site and what data to encrypt

Tags: encryption, e-commerce

Soon I will be releasing my first e-commerce site. I'm a bit paranoid about what data to encrypt or not to store at all.

I plan to use BrainTree payments and their Transparent Redirect solution which means I'm not even a proxy for the credit card payment but simply keeping the token of payment processing o the server.

In addition, I keep user shipping/billing address also basic contact info such as full name, phone and email.

My question is, beside the password (default by Django to encrypt), is it necessary/needed to encrypt the user information such as their addreses?

Comment: Passwords should be **hashed**, not encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a question you have to answer by yourself, are you willing to pay the additional cost of encryption and decryption when you want to access any of this information while storing or retrieving respectively? Is it worth the performance penalty?

The reason that you are even considering encryption is cos you are worried about your application being hacked, may be it is useful for you to spend time covering that base than worrying about what will happen once your application is hacked.

Also for encryption/decryption you need to use a key, well what guarantee that your key wont be hacked once your app has been and there on you cannot do anything as it is. Note that hashing is different from encryption and you dont get back the hashed data using the hashkey.

Some more things to be considered, do you really need to store this information or rely on an external service to provide you this if there is such an option and the user is registered with it.

Also you might want to read up on this: https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043614/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081705-1.aspx